# Finding an equation of linear classifier for two separable sets of points using perceptron learning

Tags: matlab, classification, perceptron

I would like to write a matlab function to find an equation of a linear classifier for 2 separable sets of points using one single-layer perceptron. I have got 2 files:

**script file - run.m:**

```
x_1 = [3, 3, 2, 4, 5];
y_1 = [3, 4, 5, 2, 2];
x_2 = [6, 7, 5, 9, 8];
y_2 = [3, 3, 4, 2, 5];

target_array = [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1];

[ func ] = classify_perceptron([x_1 x_2; y_1 y_2], target_array);
x = -2:10;
y = arrayfun(func, x);

plot(x_1, y_1, 'o', x_2, y_2, 'X', x, y);
axis([-2, 10, -2, 10]);
```

**classify_perceptron.m**

```
function [ func ] = classify_perceptron( points, target )
    % points - matrix of x,y coordinates
    % target - array of expected results
    % func - function handler which appropriately classifies a point
    %        given by x, y arguments supplied to this function

    target_arr = target;
    weights = rand(1, 2);
    translation = rand();

    for i=1:size(points, 2)
        flag = true;
        while flag
            result = weights * points(:, i) + translation;
            y = result > 0;
            e = target_arr(1, i) - y;

            if e ~= 0
                weights = weights + (e * points(:, i))';
                translation = translation + e;
            else
                flag = false;
            end
        end
    end

    func = @(x)(-(translation + (weights(1, 1) * x)) / weights(1, 2));

    return
end
```

The problem is that I don't know where I am making the mistake that leads to incorrect result. It looks like the slope of the line is right, however translation should be a bit bigger. I would be really thankful for pointing me in the right direction. The result I get is presented in the picture below:

[image: My result]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have made a significant progress. In case someone runs into the same problem I present to you the solution. The problem has been solved by adding a variable `learning_rate = 0.1` and packing the loop iterating over points into another loop iterating as many times as specified in the variable `epochs (e.g. 300)` .